# How to ignore negative value in random number generator

Tags: java, random

I am using the BigInteger class to generate random a large prime number but I keep getting negative value. How is it possible to ignore all the negative returns? How should I make it to a fix 10 number?

```
public class Gen{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Random rand = new SecureRandom();
        BigInteger.probablePrime(100, rand);
        System.out.println(BigInteger.probablePrime(100, rand).longValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `rann` ?? did you mean `rand`???

Comment: Can't you use Math.abs?

Comment: "*Returns a **positive** BigInteger that is probably prime*" - How are you getting a negative number? Are you sure you're looking at the right output?

Comment: rann is a typo, its rand

Comment: Is this the whole code? If not, did you try to run the exact example from above? It must return positive number in all cases.

Comment: i missed out the .longValue()..i am storing the number in long, but when i store it, it become negative

Answer (score 4):

Your error is because of overflow. A `long` in Java can only hold values up to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

If your program generates a random number bigger than this, you can get a negative value when you try to cram it into a `long`. You can see this in the [Javadoc for BigInteger#longValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue%28%29):

> *Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.*

Comment: gosh...other than long, is there anyway to store the bigger number ?

Comment: `BigInteger` is the one most commonly used, can't you keep that instead of converting it to a `long`?